# Accuracy of bone influence (rigging/weighting)

Tags: rigging, vertex-weights

I'd like to find a process or a tool so that I can :

- Place bones to define their influence precisely so that an automatic weighting will be ok
- Report their influences to another bone, as i dont have the choice of the final armature

For instance, is it possible to define children (and deform) bones and report their weights to their parent after the weighting is done ?

Comment: An exemple here https://gyazo.com/1170006d88790a3a3c631cab86aee6bd . Red bones define the influence and blue ones the rig. So in the principle i am happy, but i need more bones to define the influences, and these additionnal bones cannot go to the final armature. So, that why bone envelopes is not a solution to me.

Comment: In my experience the accuracy of automatic weighting has a lot to do with the mesh, and for the most part works well on a "good" mesh, _ie_ with good topology and modeled with the bones in mind.  I may have to edit some / all the weights later.  Agree with @shadowcopalypse in that it's a bit counter intuitive as you would need to edit the "sub-bone" locations according to the underlying mesh.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is convoluted and without purpose.

With that in mind the closest thing we have is 'Envelope' bones.

Where in its bubble defines influence.

[image]

[image]

The only bones that have weight are deform bones.

Comment: ok, i know this... but this is not what i need. Envelope weights are not precise enough. Could you explain more about "without purpose" ?

Comment: I added a comment under the subject in order to explain more precisely what i need